# load custom css stylesheet in wp-comments-post.php

Tags: wordpress, enqueue

I want the core file wp-comments-post.php in wordpress to load my custom css and js files. What hook to use to enqueue those files?

Comment: You want [this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Comment: And [this one](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to load javascript files

Comment: Thats is correct. I am looking for a hook to load them, since the default wp_enqueue_scripts does not work with that particular page.

Comment: The  enqueue functions should be added to your theme's **functions.php** file. Any file within Wordpress that has `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php` )' will have those functions available

Comment: + you can use `if` `is_page` to load styles/scripts only on pages where these are needed.